# ChartBoost ad is not displaying in my view

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

I am developing iPhone application. In that I want to use chartboost. I am new to this concept, so I used the code given in that website, but still it's not working. I used the above coding in appdelegate.m file. And added SystemConfiguration.framework and QuartzCore.framework. Is there anything else I have to do?

```
#import "Chartboost.h"
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
// Configure ChartBoost
ChartBoost *cb = [ChartBoost sharedChartBoost]; cb.appId = @"APP_ID";
cb.appSignature = @"APP_SIGNATURE";
// Notify the beginning of a user session
[cb startSession];
// Show an interstitial
[cb showInterstitial]; }
```

Comment: Are you replacing "APP_ID" and "APP_SIGNATURE" with actual values from the ChartBoost web site?  Like "4fd91..."?

Answer (score 1):

Me also faced same problem, solution is we need to create test campaign in chart boost account. [here](http://chartboost.com/campaign/marketplace_publisher)

[here is my thread about chart boost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11412496/chartboost-in-ios)

Answer (score 0):

My implementation of method to init Chartboost

```
- (void) initChartboost {

    Chartboost *cb = [Chartboost sharedChartboost];

    // Add your own app id & signature. These can be found on App Edit page for your app in the Chartboost dashboard
    cb.appId = @"YOUR APP ID FROM CB";
    cb.appSignature = @"APP SIGNATURE";

    // Begin a user session. This should be done once per boot
    [cb startSession];

    // Cache an interstitial at the default location
    [cb cacheInterstitial];

    // Cache the more apps page so it's ready & loaded
   [cb cacheMoreApps];
}
```

also pay your attention that you will see interstitial on simulator correctly but to see them on device you have to add your device UDID to Chartboost as described [here.](https://chartboost.tenderapp.com/kb/ios-integration/how-do-test-devices-work)