# Chartboost in iphone project / Chartboost usage in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, chartboost

Integrated [chartoost](https://chartboost.com/) sdk in to iPhone game. (Landscape game)

```
#define CHARTBOOST_ID @"55c9f216f6cd4572f3975566"
#define CHARTBOOST_SIG @"9cc8122cfb05bfe0e171f46990180147e8b6f23c"

[Chartboost startWithAppId:CHARTBOOST_ID appSignature:CHARTBOOST_SIG delegate:self];

[Chartboost showInterstitial:CBLocationHomeScreen];
```

But it is not displaying any ads. Help me to find what's wrong with settings in Xcode or account in chart boost.

**Notes_Warning** :

Hi All, don't use Chartboost, instead try google Admob or other ads network. Because Chartboost - a cheater! I used Chartboost in my games, game got good ranking in Cambodia - reached #1 in Racing/games. Game got good downloads too...But Chartboost said we used many device in Cambodia and downloaded game...its not true...we are not from Cambodia...I tried to send message to Chartboost many times...but they didn't respond and suspended my account. They even didn't pay my 7463$. Really its a heart attack for us. Now we removed Chartboost and used Admob and earned our development cost from Admob easily. So avoid Chartboost avoid getting cheated!!! Truth always wins...Always do good. 
**Be a good person but don't try to prove it**. Just go away from bad cheaters!!!!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Perhaps there has been an error in loading them. I would implement the delegate methods as described in [the docs](http://www.chartboost.com/support/sdk), particularly the `didFail` method:

```
// Called before requesting an interstitial from the back-end
- (BOOL)shouldRequestInterstitial:(NSString *)location;

// Called when an interstitial has been received, before it is presented on screen
// Return NO if showing an interstitial is currently inappropriate, for example if the user has entered the main game mode
- (BOOL)shouldDisplayInterstitial:(NSString *)location;

// Called when the user dismisses the interstitial
- (void)didDismissInterstitial:(NSString *)location;

// Same as above, but only called when dismissed for a close
- (void)didCloseInterstitial:(NSString *)location;

// Same as above, but only called when dismissed for a click
- (void)didClickInterstitial:(NSString *)location;

// Called when an interstitial has failed to come back from the server
// This may be due to network connection or that no interstitial is available for that user
- (void)didFailToLoadInterstitial:(NSString *)location;
```

Comment: Now added above delegates, YES, didFailToLoadInterstitial  method is called. What wrong? anything from my side ? if so then where is mistake? in Xcode settings Or in my chart boost account? how can i resolve this error?

Comment: I don't use this service, but the message says that it could be either network connection or no ad for the user.

Comment: I helped you farthest anybody can on SO. You need to determine if it is your network, or contact Chartboost to see why no interstitial is available.

Comment: No problem with network as other service works in same app. Ok, I can report in chart boost site. Thank you.

Answer (score 17):

**Notes_Warning** :

Hi All, **don't use Chartboost**, instead try google Admob or other ads network. Because **Chartboost - a cheater**! I used Chartboost in my games, game got good ranking in Cambodia - reached #1 in Racing/games. Game got good downloads too...But Chartboost said we used many device in Cambodia and downloaded game...its not true...we are not from Cambodia...I tried to send message to Chartboost many times...but they didn't respond and suspended my account. They even didn't pay my 7463$. Really its a heart attack for us. Now we removed Chartboost and used Admob and earned our development cost from Admob easily. So avoid Chartboost avoid getting cheated!!! Truth always wins...Always do good. Be a good person but don't try to prove it. Just go away from bad cheaters!!!!

---

Now its working fine. We need to add publishing campaign in our chartboost account. [Here](http://chartboost.com/campaign)

[image]

**UPDATES:**

```
 [Chartboost startWithAppId:CHARTBOOST_APP_ID appSignature:CHARTBOOST_APP_SIGNATURE delegate:self];
 [Chartboost  showInterstitial:CBLocationHomeScreen];
```

## Some other way to see test Ads:

- Add your device UDID in publishing campaign
  [image: how to add your device UDID in publishing campaign]
  [image: how to add your device UDID in publishing campaign]
- Enable test mode in App settings. 
  [image: how to enable test mode in App settings?]

Comment: Where to Add the test devices? The Site doesn't showing anything!

Comment: @iTroyd23, looks like they updated UI now, email: support@chartboost.com  they tell for sure. Happy coding.

Comment: thank you. Even to delete a app we need to mail `support@chartboost.com`.

Answer (score 2):

It may also be because the Campaign is not filling adverts and you have not added the devices as test devices to force the adverts to be filled.

This is easily missed since at first adverts may be filled - only during testing they'll just stop mysteriously.

There is a setting in Chartboost:

Edit the Campaign you are using for testing

- Under "Campaign Logic" click the "Show Test Devices" button.
- Click "Add Test Device" to add each device.
- Enable each device and Save the Campaign.

(Don't forget to un-tick them when live - since I assume that missing that will mean those devices keep seeing adverts but you probably want to see how the app really behaves)

Answer (score 2):

You need to set

cb.delegate = self;