# Chartboost version 3.0.4

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4.3, ios5.1

I'm working with `chartboost sdk version 3.0.4`. It does load successfully in my app. But the problem is it takes `too much time to load`. Moreover it does not load with loader indicator. IS there any solution to come out from this to user friendly approach?

Thanking You in Advance

Comment: When are you showing this interstitial? At app startup?

Comment: @JesseRusak No, I'm showing it on some event occurence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After searching for so long. Finally I got the hint from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11413000/1538079).

Any other suitable answer is still appreciated.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't make your users wait for the interstitial to show. One way to do this is to use the [Chartboost caching features](https://help.chartboost.com/documentation/ios/caching) to fetch the interstitial before you need it.

For example, you could call `[cb cacheInterstitial];` when your app first starts and then when you later call `[cb showInterstitial];` it should happen immediately. (The docs also describe how to re-cache the interstitial after you show it the first time.)

Comment: @ForamMukundShah Did you also implement the `didDismissInterstitial:` that the docs I linked to suggested to re-cache for next time?

Comment: No, I've just shared chartboost with its appid & app signature. After that I'm starting session & showing interstitial. Rest I have not implemented any delegate methods. Thhat's why I have referred my answer given below.