# ChartBoost not Showing Interstitial

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, chartboost

I have followed example from [Chartboost](https://codeload.github.com/ChartBoost/client-examples/zip/master) i iOS. Even I have checkout all the Questions from Stackoverflow too. I have used their suggestions too, but not found Interstitials.
Even I have allow publish in network in Chartboost dashboard.

It works fine for the Firsttime when App is Installed on device and even if we delete the app and run xcode still the same issue that Chartboost not showing Interstitial. Every time it calls method as follows:

```
- (void)didFailToLoadInterstitial:(NSString *)location
```

I have also included below method:

```
- (void)didDismissInterstitial:(NSString *)location {
    NSLog(@"chartboost*** dismissed interstitial at location %@", location);

    [[Chartboost sharedChartboost] cacheInterstitial:location];
}
```

I haven't seen the Chartboost Ad in my App. I have also included the Method as follow to check whether Caching is available or not.

```
BOOL isCached = [[Chartboost sharedChartboost] hasCachedInterstitial:@"After level 1"];
```

and returns NO. In two screens I need Advertisement from chartboost. And I have given them two different Location Names too and calls them whenever needed.

How to overcome from this issue??

Comment: checkout my answer in this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11412496/chartboost-in-iphone-project-chartboost-usage-in-ios

Answer (score 0):

It's been 2 years so you already know the solution to your questions but for those who face this issue, you have to wait a few minutes sometimes even over 10 minutes for the 1st interstitial chartboost to show up whether live or test ad. When you delete your app and re-run it again on Xcode you have to wait again a long time. Sometimes longer than 10 minutes.