# How to return YES to a BOOL in an AppDelegate class?

Tags: ios, objective-c, chartboost

I have been working on my first app for a few months and am at the stage where I need to add advertising before I send it to the App store. I have added iAD successfully and am trying to configure Chartboost.

I run into problems when I try to stop Chartboost from showing Interstitials at certain parts of my game. I have set up locations as per the documentation on the Chartboost website and in the Chartboost.h file it states:

```
// Return NO if showing an interstitial is currently inappropriate, for example if the user has entered the main game mode
- (BOOL)shouldDisplayInterstitial:(NSString *)location;
```

Sorry if this sounds like a silly question but I've been searching through my iOS book and online for the answer which I'm sure is simple. How do I return YES to (BOOL)shouldDisplayInterstitial from another class. I.E from my GameViewController.m ?

Comment: Infact this method is supposed to return YES or NO, while expects a string as parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**How do i return that YES/No from other class?**

**1.Delegate is matter. Set delegate of Chartboost to your GameViewController class**

```
Chartboost *cb = [Chartboost sharedChartboost];
cb.delegate = self;//Specify your GameViewController object instead of self;
```

**2.implement the method in your class**

```
 - (BOOL)shouldDisplayInterstitial:(NSString *)location
 {
    return YES;
 }
```

**Best Practices: [Source](https://help.chartboost.com/documentation/ios)**

First run experience

It's good practice (and noted in the iOS Human Interface Guidelines) to show interstitials only after the user has played your game for the first time.

You can use the below Chartboost SDK delegate method to prevent interstitials until the second startSession:

```
- (BOOL)shouldRequestInterstitialsInFirstSession {
    return NO;
}
```

Refer this example

https://github.com/ChartBoost/client-examples/blob/master/iOS/ChartboostExample/ExampleAppAppDelegate.m

[Chartboost in iphone project / Chartboost usage in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11412496/chartboost-in-iphone-project-chartboost-usage-in-ios)

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any examples of how to return NO at a certain part in the game (From a different class) to the (BOOL)shouldDisplayInterstitial in app delegate. Do you know of any on github?

Comment: I can't get your question

Comment: Hello @Vijay-Apple-Dev.blogspot.com I found out how to do it. Here's the sample code: [link](https://gist.github.com/DanielTomlinson/8a59a9cd64a911a0f3a4) You create a VOID method in the Appdelegate and  use that to pass the return value to the BOOL method. Worked a treat!

Answer (score 0):

1) You created a `Chartboost` object and set a delegate to it.

```
Chartboost *cb = [Chartboost sharedChartboost];
cb.delegate = self;
```

2) Self if a delegate that needs to implement `shouldDisplayInterstitial` method

```
- (BOOL)shouldDisplayInterstitial:(NSString *)location
{
    return YES;
}
```

See [example project here](https://github.com/ChartBoost/client-examples/archive/master.zip)

Comment: So in my GameViewController where I want to return a NO to shouldDisplayInterstitial: should I call the CB delegate then send NO or FALSE to the BOOL in AppDelegate. How would I construct this? I'm assuming something like this: [cb shouldDisplayInterstitial(NO)]; ?

Answer (score 0):

Through delegation. If the class where you need to declare `shouldDisplayInterstitial:` cannot answer the question, it should ask a class that can:

```
- (BOOL) shouldDisplayInterstitial: (NSString *)location
{
    return [self.delegate shouldDisplayInterstitial:location];
}
```

Your delegate should conform to a specific protocol and implement the method.

More on delegation can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/DelegatesandDataSources/DelegatesandDataSources.html).